# Alexnet CNN error occurs when i Fit model

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

Link of code
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MyACfSmaaZ0Gnfy3NgOm2kltvdMheWZP?usp=sharing

Error when i run model in history statement
[Image what error coming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQdJU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1L8Z.png)

I didn't understand why error coming how to resolve it.

Comment: Change this `model.add(Dense(1000, activation='softmax'))` to `model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))`, as you only have `2` classes. Also try copy-paste the error instead of screenshots

Comment: Also I am not sure if `softmax` should be applied, as I'm not sure what is the default settings for `categorical_crossentropy` (specifically `from_logits`). And if you are using tensorflow backend, try switching to `tf.keras` instead

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link to external code locations or embed images of code/errors. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability to others as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888). Please also review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).